# Get the graphics card model?

Tags: c++, graphics, model, directx, intel

I was wondering how I can get the graphics card model/brand from code particularly from DirectX 9.0c (from within C++ code).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At runtime, you can query the device model and vendor:

- In OpenGL, use the command glGetString(GL_VENDOR) or GL_RENDERER or GL_VERSION to get the information you're after.
- In DirectX 9, it appears the info is in the Microsoft config system, and is queried from the device database.  It's section 3 of this document, which also has example code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204848(VS.85).aspx
  Using the same system you can get such information as the amount of ram the video card has, the driver number, etc.

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way in DirectX is through [IDirect3D9::GetAdapterIdentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174317%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Just create a [D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object, pass a pointer to it to GetAdapterIdentifier.  DirectX fills out the graphics card description as a string in the Description field.  It also includes information on which display device the card is, and what driver version you have.

You get something like this:

- Description: "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 570"
- Device: "\.\DISPLAY1"
- Driver:
  "nvd3dum.dll"

Comment: Thanks got the information I needed and was very useful not sure why this isn't the accepted answer.

Comment: ... because it's three years later. :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Chapter 2. Direct3D](http://www.xmission.com/~legalize/book/download/02-Direct3D.pdf) from my book [The Direct3D Graphics Pipeline](http://www.xmission.com/~legalize/book/download/).  See section 2.12, Identifying a Particular Device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "DirecX Diagnostic Tool" API, like in sample DxDiagOutput from DX SDK
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416986%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
IDirect3D9* d3dobject = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpresent;
memset(&d3dpresent, 0, sizeof(D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS));
d3dpresent.Windowed = TRUE;
d3dpresent.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
UINT adaptercount = d3dobject->GetAdapterCount();
D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER9* adapters = (D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER9*)malloc(sizeof(D3DADAPTER_IDENTIFIER9) * adaptercount);

for (int i = 0; i < adaptercount; i++)
{
      d3dobject->GetAdapterIdentifier(i, 0, &(adapters[i]));
}
```

Then get the description of adapters (adapters->Description)

Comment: You don't need D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS here. It's used for device creation in D3D9. Adapter info is available without it.