# Difference between Direct3D and DXGI

Tags: c++, windows, nvidia, direct3d, dxgi

I'm trying to query a Windows machine, using C++, for a list of available graphics cards.

This SO question has an answer (from moxize) which provides one way (d3d9.h):
[get-the-graphics-card-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090261/get-the-graphics-card-model)

And this one provides another (dxgi.h): [dxgi enumadapters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgifactory-enumadapters)

When I tried each, I found the dxgi method above listed **all** the cards whilst the d3d9 one seemed only to provide **one** of them, depending on the selection of the "preferred graphics processor" in the NVIDIA control panel.

I'm struggling to understand the difference between what each of the above programmatic routes provides and is meant to be used for?

Comment: In case it's of interest, I used the CUDA Driver API in the end, provided by nvcuda.dll in C:\Windows\System32. Sections Version Management and Device Management gave me what I was after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DirectX Graphics Infrastructure (DXGI) was introduced with Vista. It basically factored all the enumeration, display and adapter management, and presentation stuff out of Direct3D. That way, all sorts of graphics APIs can coexist without a need to have separate mechanisms for these common tasks in each of them. It allows, e.g., all the Direct3D APIs (>= 10) to only be concerned with drawing 3D content into buffers and not care about where these buffers come from, or whether and how they are going to be displayed.

The old Direct3D 9 API still has its own interface for adapter enumeration. If I remember correctly, Direct3D 9 used to only enumerate adapters that actually had a display connected. Most likely because the API didn't really have support for headless rendering, so it wouldn't make sense to try use an adapter without an output. DXGI, on the other hand, operates on a more complete picture of the whole [video and present network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/introduction-to-video-present-networks) on your machine. Most importantly, it differentiates between adapters (graphics cards), and outputs (displays connected to an adapter). I assume you're running on a laptop or some other machine with an integrated as well as a dedicated GPU!? Switching the "preferred graphics processor" in the driver control panel will, most likely, change which of the two GPUs is (logically) connected to the display. And Direct3D 9 will then always only enumerate that one…

Comment: Note that the latest version of DXGI 1.6 that comes with Windows 10 April 2018 Update has better explicit support for dealing with laptops with both discrete and integrated GPUs rather than the somewhat hacky things that the controls panels have done. See [DeviceResources](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/blob/master/d3d11game_win32_dr/DeviceResources.cpp) and [this commit](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/commit/e6406ee9afaf2719ff29b68c63c7adbcac57c02a).